# pandas ascend sort multiple columns but reverse sort one column

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

I have a pandas DataFrame that has a little over 100 columns.

There are about 50 columns that I want to sort ascending and then there is one column (a date_time column) that I want to reverse sort.

How do I go about achieving this? I know I can do something like...

```
df = df.sort_values(by = ['column_001', 'column_003', 'column_009', 'column_017',... 'date_time'], ascending=[True, True, True, True,... False])
```

... but I am trying to avoid having to type 'True' 50 times.

Just wondering if there is a quick hand way of doing this.

Thanks.

Dan

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
cols = ['column_001', 'column_003', 'column_009', 'column_017',... 'date_time']
df.sort_values(by=cols, ascending=[True]*49+[False])
```

Or, for a programmatic variant for which you don't need to know the position of the `False`, using [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy):

```
cols = ['column_001', 'column_003', 'column_009', 'column_017',... 'date_time']
df.sort_values(by=cols, ascending=np.array(cols)!='date_time')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `filter` if your 49 columns have a regular pattern:

```
# if you have a column name pattern
cols = df.filter(regex=('^(column_|date_time)')).columns.tolist()
ascending_false = ['date_time']
ascending = [True if c not in ascending_false else False for c in cols]

df.sort_values(by=cols, ascending=ascending)
```

Example:

```
>>> df
   column_0  column_1  date_time  value  other_value  another_value
0         4         2          6      6            1              1
1         4         4          0      6            0              2
2         3         2          6      9            0              7
3         9         2          1      7            4              7
4         6         9          2      4            4              1

>>> df.sort_values(by=cols, ascending=ascending)
   column_0  column_1  date_time  value  other_value  another_value
2         3         2          6      9            0              7
0         4         2          6      6            1              1
1         4         4          0      6            0              2
4         6         9          2      4            4              1
3         9         2          1      7            4              7
```

Answer (score 1):

It should go something like this.

```
to_be_reserved = "COLUMN_TO_BE_RESERVED"
df = df.sort_values(by=[col for col in df.columns if col != to_be_reserved],ignore_index=True)
df[to_be_reserved] = df[to_be_reserved].sort_values(ascending=False,ignore_index = True)
```